# Cummulative substraction of 2 values using SQL or Python

Tags: python, mysql, databricks, databricks-sql

| rake_name | origin | destination | created_At | bpc_issue_date | departure_time | journey_distance | bpc_balance_distance_km | abc | rn | logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 09-02-2024 06:37 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 09-02-2024 13:40 | 173.4600067 | 5271 | 5097.539993 | 1 | 5271-173.4600067 |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 11-02-2024 02:58 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 11-02-2024 04:15 | 1099.369995 | 5271 | 3998 | 2 | 5097-1099 |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 14-02-2024 12:46 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 14-02-2024 15:50 | 1099.369995 | 5271 | 2898 | 3 | 3998-1099 |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 16-02-2024 17:29 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 17-02-2024 02:30 | 175.6600037 | 5271 | 2713 | 4 | 2898-175 |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 17-02-2024 10:54 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 18-02-2024 11:30 | 1178.880005 | 5271 | 1544 | 5 | 2713-1178 |
| ARIL-05 | a | b | 20-02-2024 11:44 | 08-02-2024 18:30 | 20-02-2024 15:20 | 1179.369995 | 5271 | 364 | 6 | 1544-1179 |

Please look at the logic column for substraction i want.

so i want to update abc column with difference between bpc_balance_distance_km and journey_distance once i get that value i want to substract below abc values with the `result of abc - respective journey_distance`.

i have tried sql, however i am not sure how can i populate row >1, am able to populate 1st row using
`case when rn= 1 then bpc_balance_km - journey_distance`

i have tried following query however, i awnt to covert this query int databricks sql supported query. this query works

```
SET @newabc := 0;

WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN @newabc := bpc_balance_distance_km-journey_distance
         ELSE @newabc := @newabc-journey_distance END AS nabc
 FROM derived_abc ORDER BY rn)
 SELECT *, ROUND(nabc) AS final_result
 FROM cte;
```

any suggastion in python or sql will be helpful.
here is DB fiddle link : https://dbfiddle.uk/JBzaylSb i am using databricks sql

Comment: You can use pandas to add or remove columns easily based on other columns in the dataset. However, it is actually not clear what you exactly want in the code. Could you please rephrase the description of the equation you are trying to build?

Comment: @ArpitOmprakash please have a look at the logic column, based on that substraction i am trying to populate abc column.

Comment: How do you treat the decimal in your `journey_distance`? Your `abc` values are inconsistent, the first result return with decimal then in the subsequent results, you've omitted the decimal entirely. Furthermore, the `abc` value for `rn=4` onwards are incorrect. `2898-175=2723`, not `2713`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
SET @newabc := 0;

WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN @newabc := bpc_balance_distance_km-journey_distance
         ELSE @newabc := @newabc-journey_distance END AS nabc
 FROM derived_abc ORDER BY rn)
 SELECT *, ROUND(nabc) AS final_result
 FROM cte;
```

In the query above, the value of `bpc_balance_distance_km-journey_distance` for `rn=1` is assigned to the `@newabc` variable. Then for rows where `rn > 1`, it'll take the current assigned `@newabc` value to subtract with the row's `journey_distance` value.

There'll be a slight different result in which causes by what I already point out in the comment - the inconsistencies of the decimal treatment. You can see the example in this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OynBg5Jh).

Comment: this works but i am using databricks sql, it is not letting me set dynamic variable, any idea how can we do that in databricks sql?

Comment: First of all, you failed to mention `databricks` involvement in this and I'm not familiar with it. Secondly, what do you mean by "not letting me set dynamic variable"? Any error?

Comment: can u write same query with another approch ? without SET @newabc := 0; ? i mean we need to assign one value we might can do `select 0 as newabc from table`

Comment: Can you try to remove that yourself first and see what it does? In most cases, that part is not necessary but if you receive error or not getting the right result after removing that, please update the details in your question.

Comment: i have written python function it worked. thanks for ur answer it is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_nabc(rn, bpc_balance_distance_km, journey_distance, newabc):
    if rn == 1:
        newabc[0] = bpc_balance_distance_km - journey_distance
    else:
        newabc[0] = newabc[0] - journey_distance
    return newabc[0]

def calculate_final_result(df):
    # Add a row number column
    df['rn'] = df.groupby('rake_name').cumcount() + 1
    
    # Initialize the value of newabc
    newabc = [0.0]

    # Calculate the nabc column using the UDF
    df['nabc'] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_nabc(row['rn'], row['bpc_balance_distance_km'], row['journey_distance'], newabc), axis=1)

    # Round the nabc values
    df['final_result'] = df['nabc'].round()

    return df
df = calculate_final_result(df)
df.display()
```

Comment: this works also in python